# Web Skype Does Not Work on Google Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, skype

All of a sudden when trying to open https://web.skype.com I'm presented with the following error:

[image]

It seems that the Linux version of Chrome is also not supported, [alongside a plethora of other browsers](https://newslair.com/2019/03/11/skype-for-web-officially-drops-support-for-safari-firefox-opera/).

EDIT: This seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary workaround is to change your user agent. Open the web inspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>), Click on the three dots button in the top right (*Customize and control DevTools*), then *More Tools* and then *Network Conditions*. Untick *User Agent* and select *Chrome - Windows*.

More discussion and source of this solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/what-is-wrong-with-skype-now-google-chrome-is-not/6e5c51ff-178f-44a0-88fe-75d460829adf).